# Can you make a lightsaber?

Tags: visible-light, laser, plasma-physics

Would be possible to create a light saber using photons or plasma, like the ones in the Star Wars movies? If not what forbids it? What is the physics behind these sabers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No** it's not possible using conventional laser technology. The plasma approach makes more sense but the design would be quite different from the light sabers we see in Star Wars.
I would recommend **[THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lr5OUjFDkg)** video by Michio Kaku.